# Multidimensional array with custom index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I make multidimensional array in javascript in the following format:

```
Array[

{index}:{x-coords}
        {y-coords},

{index2}:{x-coords}
        {y-coords},
.... ];
```

The data should look like as follows:

```
Array[
{
indexabc:{10},{20}
},
{
indexxyz:{30},{40}
}
];
```

Also, how to access the array elements? I am storing value in them through a function so it will be called recursively.

Comment: please add some example data.

Comment: show how should look the expected result for your case

Comment: @NinaScholz  please see the sample data

Comment: Where you get this notation? it's not javascript.

Comment: please add the purpose to the question, because it makes a huge difference to the data structure, for example if you need iterable data structure, then an array would be better than an object with keys. but if you know the keys, for example a linked list, the an object structure would be better. so its up to you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = [[x-coords, y-coords], [x-coords, y-coords]...]
```

is a multidimensional array, however if you want key - value pairs, you might want to use an object

```
var obj = {
    index: [x-coords, y-coords],
    index2: [x-coords, y-coords],
    ...
}
```

to fit your data either use William B's answer or something like that

```
var obj = {
    indexabc: [10, 20],
    indexxyz: [30, 40]
}
```

so you can access data like so

```
obj.indexabc[0]
```

Comment: Please look at the sample data and suggest

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want plain old Object:

```
var o = {
  indexabc: { x: 10, y: 20},
  indexxyz: { x: 30, y: 40 }
};

console.log( o.indexabc.x, o.indexabc.y );
```

Comment: Please look at the sample data and suggest

Comment: I've updated my answer to match your sample data, and to show how to access the data as well. But I suggest taking an online JS tutorial to better understand Objects and Arrays

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to create a two-dimensional array you can easy do like that:

```
var a = [];
a[0] = [1,2];
a[1] = [2,3];
console.log(a[0]) // [1,2]
```

Comment: Please look at the sample data and suggest